# How to add a SKSpriteNode to the scene in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclass, skspritenode, addchild

I tried to subclass `SKSpriteNode` into `GameObject` and I would like to instantiate objects outside the game scene class. Here is my `GameObject` code derived from `SKSpriteNode`:

```
import SpriteKit

public class GameObject: SKSpriteNode {

    init( texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize, position:CGPoint, name:String ) 
    {   
        objectSize = size;
        objectName = name;
        objectSprite = texture;
        //call superclass here
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size);
        self.position = position;
    }

    convenience init(_ _x:CGFloat, _ _y:CGFloat, _ _object:String )// Default initializer
    {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: _object);
        let position = CGPoint(x:_x, y:_y);
        self.init(  texture: texture,color: UIColor(),size: texture.size(), position: position, name: _object);
    }

    //Overloaded initializer with size as extra argument
    convenience init(_ _x:CGFloat, _ _y:CGFloat, _ _size:Int, _ _object:String)
    {
        //size for the SKSpriteNode.
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: _object);
        let position = CGPoint(x:_x, y:_y);
        self.init(  texture: texture, color: UIColor(), size: CGSize(width: _size, height: _size),position: position, name: _object);
    }
```

To instantiate a player derived from `GameObject`, I have to write:

```
let player = PlayerShip(100, 100, "PlayerShip")
addChild(player)
```

However, `addChild()` does not work outside `gameScene`. My goal is to instantiate bullets from the `PlayerShip` class, but i can't figure out how. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: From question it is not clear what you want to do. At what point do you call this method `addChild`? And more code where you call it. Describe the purpose of create objects in more detail. So you're not create them on the scene and in another object, and then add them to the scene?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this outside of GameScene you need a kind go global property which has a reference to the GameScene. Then you can call:

```
myGameScene.AddChild(player)
```