# iOS - Adding a 2D image to a scenekit game

Tags: ios, scenekit

Hello i can't for the life of me work out how to add a 2D image in the scene using scenekit is it even possible? What I'm trying to accomplish is have a 3D flying plane over a 2D background image but the background image can't cover the whole screen. Thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: are you working in swift or objective c? what have you tried? what has and hasn't worked?

Comment: I'm working in swift and I've tried using a uiimage and tried making a skspritenode but i couldn't find a way to add it to the scene

Comment: have you tried searching stack overflow? this may help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/33900358/3033386

Comment: Yes I have and thanks for the link but they are using the SpriteKit framework I'm using the SceneKit framework

Comment: have you tried apple's scene kit framework reference? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/index.html

Comment: although i have no experience with this sort of thing, it would seem like you could try rendering it as a 3d image with a very small value for the thickness (0.000001 or something). Could that work?

Answer (score 9):

Others have said plenty good suggestions above.

#### Let me summarize each solution with different scenarios:

- Using `scnScene.background`: Easiest, but fullscreen and static. You cannot display in a smaller area of the scene, nor can you customize the transformations.
- Using `scnScene.overlaySKScene` to display a 2D `SKScene` and adding image sprite. This is probably what fits your scenario. If you want *static* but with configurable transformations, this is a good choice. Notably `overlaySKScene` is recommended by Apple to create HUD in your 3D scene.

  > However, if you want the 2D content to track the 3D movement, you need to do some coordinate conversion from 3D space to 2D space every frame. Bad news is the job is done by CPU, which will add performance drag. (Believe me, this frustrate me too!)
- Using `SCNNode` with `SCNPlane` geometry and set the `diffuse.content` with the image; add `SCNBillBoardConstraint` to the node to ensure it's always facing the camera.

  > Most flexible. However if your camera is not orthographic, the picture is going to zoom as the fov of camera changes, which doesn't look 2D but rather a hanging 3D billboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [background](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNScene_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNScene/background) property on SCNScene to set a background image.

```
scnScene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "myImage")
```

**[Contents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterialProperty_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterialProperty/contents)**

> You can set a value for this property using any of the following
>   types:
>
> A color (NSColor/UIColor or CGColorRef), specifying a constant color
>   across the material’s surface
>
> **An image (NSImage/UIImage or CGImageRef), specifying a texture to be
>   mapped across the material’s surface**
>
> An NSString or NSURL object specifying the location of an image file
>
> An array of six images (NSArray), specifying the faces of a cube map
>
> A Core Animation layer (CALayer)
>
> A texture (SKTexture, MDLTexture, MTLTexture, or GLKTextureInfo)
>
> A Sprite Kit scene (SKScene)

Answer (score 2):

SceneKit and SpriteKit play very nicely together.

Implement the background 2D image as a SceneKit node with SCNPlane geometry, using your image as the plane's material. If you want to get fancier, use a full, live SpriteKit scene as the SCNPlane's material. Place that node at the far end of your camera's frustum, with your 3D aircraft in front of it.

You might also consider providing a cube map (skybox) as your scene's background. See `SCNScene.background`.